# Parent li overlaps child li, having absolute uls, relative lis

Tags: css

I am creating a topmenu for a webpage, and with scripting, the sub menus pops up on hover. I have also taken measures to not let the menu grow too far to the right, by if needed let it grow in the other direction. This picture clarifies:

[image]

I do this by adding the class "to-the-left" to the sub sub menu.

Now, why is some menu items of the parent on top of my sub sub menu? You can read "Item 3" below "Sub sub item 2" which should not be possible.

I have tried to add z-index to the sub sub menu without succeeding.

http://jsfiddle.net/VK7Mt/

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.top-menu
            {
                    width: 920px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
            }

            div.top-menu ul.topmenu
            {
                    margin: 0;
                    height: 41px;
                    background: #ccc;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: relative;
            }

            ul.topmenu li
            {
                    list-style: none;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 12px 19px;
                    min-height: 17px;
                    position: relative;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul
            {
                    width: 190px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 41px;
                    left: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    background: #dddddd;
                    border: #c4c4c4 1px solid;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul li
            {
                    float: none;
                    padding: 3px 6px 3px 13px;
            }

            ul.topmenu a
            {
                    color: #333;
                    text-decoration: none;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul li a
            {
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    width: 90%;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul li:hover
            {
                    background: #3399cc;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul ul
            {
                    left: 100%;
                    top: 0;
            }

            ul.topmenu div
            {
                    cursor: pointer;
            }

            .topmenu-sub-item > .item
            {
                    padding-left: 6px;
            }

            .topmenu-sub-item > .item > a
            {
                    margin-top: 3px;
                    margin-bottom: 3px;
            }

            ul.topmenu ul ul.to-the-left
            {
                    left: -100.5%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="top-menu">
        <ul class="topmenu">
            <li class="topmenu-root-node">
            <a href="foobar.html">root item</a>
            <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container">
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/item1">item 1</a>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                    <div class="item has-submenu">
                        <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/item2">item 2</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container to-the-right">
                        <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                            <div class="item has-submenu">
                                <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/subitem1">Sub item 1</a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container to-the-right">
                                <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                                    <div class="item has-submenu">
                                        <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/subsubitem1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <a href="/subsubitem2">Sub sub item 2</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <a href="/subsubitem3">Sub sub item 3</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/item3">Item 3</a>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="top-menu" style="margin-top: 170px">
        <ul class="topmenu">
            <li class="topmenu-root-node">
            <a href="foobar.html">root item</a>
            <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container">
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/item1">item 1</a>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                    <div class="item has-submenu">
                        <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/item2">item 2</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container to-the-right">
                        <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                            <div class="item has-submenu">
                                <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/subitem1">Sub item 1</a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="topmenu-submenu-container to-the-left">
                                <li class="topmenu-sub-item nonempty">
                                    <div class="item has-submenu">
                                        <a class="topmenu-hassubmenu" href="/subsubitem1">Sub sub item 1</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <a href="/subsubitem2">Sub sub item 2</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                                <div class="item">
                                    <a href="/subsubitem3">Sub sub item 3</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="topmenu-sub-item">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="/item3">Item 3</a>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the order of the elements matters: elements that come later in code, are on top of the previous elements.

In your case, the subsubs are a part of the main Item 2 >> are BELOW the afterwards following Item 3.

You can override this using z-index for the sub-menu (not the subsub):

```
ul.topmenu ul {
  ...
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  ...
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VK7Mt/3/

Comment: Because then the sub would stay without z-index and a subsub within it could never reach a higher z-index (a z-index of 999 for subsub would then only affect the order within sub, but not for the whole document). If you want subsub above sub above topmenu, then you should structure z-index clearly: topmenu at 1, sub at 2.

Comment: To be clear, what would topmenu 1, sub 2 and subsub 3 result in?

Comment: it's generally difficult if the subs are nested tags of the topmenu. I would prefer independent (=not nested) ul/li-lists for topmenu, sub and subsub, that way you could simply set up a z-index hierarchy (z-index:1 for topmenu, 2 for sub, 3 for subsub.
When handling nested tags, you don't have many choices but position the subs absolute (as you did, so they are at least above the topmenu items as long as they get a z-index) and hope that the subsubs never interfere.

Answer (score 2):

Add z-index to:

```
ul.topmenu ul ul.to-the-left {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

That way you are saying that you want that ul to be in front of other elements. It had position absolute so it needed some z-index.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VK7Mt/2/)